# Apache as Proxy to Mongrel. PHP not parsing

Tags: apache-2.2, php, proxy, mongrel-cluster

I've defined the following config to proxy Apache traffic to Mongrel to run Redmine.

At this point all the php scripts are now downloaded by the browser instead of being parsed. Once I remove this config every thing goes back to normal.

Is there anything I might be missing or is there a miss configuration ? Unfortunately there are no errors in neither apache error_log nor in `php_error.log`.

```
#define mongrel cluster
<proxy balancer://mongrelcluster>
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:81
</proxy>



#forward requests to mongrel cluster
<virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias  host.domain.com
  ServerAlias <server ip>  

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass / balancer://mongrelcluster/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mongrelcluster/  
</virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your backend is not parsing the PHP scripts, the problem lies in the backend.